# How can I programmatically click a button on a MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a radiobutton when i check it , it should give a message

```
DialogResult click = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to convert the actual values to US Customary ?\n Clicking No changes just the unit system.", "Change Unit Systems to US Customary", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

if (click == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //some code 
}
```

how can I answer this message from internal code in a button to be NO ?

Comment: The only way you could do that would be using code on a different thread. `MessageBox.Show` blocks until a button is clicked so you can't do anything else on the UI thread until that happens. Maybe, if you don't want that message shown, don't write code to show the message in the first place.

Comment: Exactly that what I want , I dont want the message to appear how I can do that ?

Comment: Based on the DialogResult value you are calling different methods? Then you should call that method from button click code without showing the message box

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the message to appear

If you seriously don't want it then just perform your action when the check changes for that radio button.

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Validate to make sore it was not just deselected
   if (radioButton1.Checked)
   {
     //Do whatever I want when the use checks this radio button
   {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you click on radio button you send the appropiate delegate function(action) and Messagebox result.
The action handles yes/no cases.

```
public void HandleMessageBoxResult(DialogResult result, Action<DialogResult> action)
{
    action(result);
}


public void Radio1Action(DialogResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            MessageBox.Show("Yes Clicked for Radio1");
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            MessageBox.Show("No Clicked for Radio1");
            break;
    }
}

public void Radio2Action(DialogResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            MessageBox.Show("Yes Clicked for radioButton2");
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            MessageBox.Show("No Clicked for radioButton2");
            break;
    }
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Message for radioButton1", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
        HandleMessageBoxResult(result, Radio1Action);
    }
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Message for radioButton2", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
        HandleMessageBoxResult(result, Radio2Action);
    }
}
```

Comment: This messagebox assigned for a radio button , when you click the radio button it will shown , I have another button will change the radio button so I dont want the message to show for the user I need to give it a default answer NO if the button clicked not the radio button changed .

Comment: Hi. I update the answer. Check if it is the desired objective.